# Use a private function in header as #define in c

Tags: c, function, prototype

I have a function `f` which is:

```
void f(int x, int y, int z){
    //bla bla bla
}
```

and some other functions which use `f`:

```
void g(int x, int y, int z){
    f(x, 10, 10); //10, 10 are hard coded
}
void h(int x, int y){
    f(x, y, 20); //20 is hard coded
}
```

**IMPORTANT:** `f` is must stay private and hidden to other files.

Now, in the header file, I **JUST** write the prototypes of `h` and `g`. Everything is OK.

I decided to use `#define` for `h` & `g`, cause it's much easier and more standard. So I removed the functions and wrote this on the header:

```
#define h(x)       f(x, 10, 10)
#define g(x, y)    f(x, y, 10)
```

The problem is, as you know, I have to write the prototype of `f` in the header. `f` must be private. Is there any way that I can use #define in this scenario at all? Like using `#def`, `#undef`, ...

<sub>Note: Feel free to change the topic</sub>

Comment: I don't see why `f` should be hidden from other files. Just don't use it, or define the prototype in the files where you do need it. There's some things you can do with visibility attributes, but that's more for exporting libraries, not for internal functions.

Comment: Why the use of a macro. If anything, the best practices recommendation is to avoid using macros where possible.

Comment: `cause it's much easier and more standard` - do you have a source for this being more standard?

Comment: @Cheatah I'm writing a lib.

Comment: @datenwolf avoid using macros? Would you please share your experience with macros with me? I like using them. They're easy and simple. Why to 'avoid'??

Comment: @msbit What's the problem with macros:))) I use them a lot. In my opinion, macros have more priority over functions. Which one do you prefer? `#define check_timeout(now, last, timeout) (now - last > timeout)` or a whole function which does the same?

Comment: That last example is a great one where you don't use a function or a macro. But if I had to, I'd write a function and trust the compiler to optimise it away.

Comment: @Cheatah I couldn't get you. What do you mean by "That last example"?

Comment: Macros are not “more standard” than functions. Macros do not “have more priority” over functions. It is dubious that macros are “much easier” than functions. This question is based on false premises. To keep a function private, do not use it in macros that are visible.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I think I have a different definition of `macro`. Macros, as I think, are used when I want to 1) define multiple different things which refer to a special thing (this question), 2) where you need to define a function with just 1 line of code, you simply use macros. (Please look at my reply to @msbit)

Comment: Consider using inline function rather than a macro

Comment: @MohammadKholghi: macros perfrom simple text replacement by the C preprocessor. Try to step into a macro using a debugger, or attemt to dereference them? The mere fact that you have to ask about the issues macros pose, is reason enough, that you absolutely, most definitely should not use them, because very apparently you don't seem to understand how they work, or what their use implies.

Comment: @MohammadKholghi for the "functions that are only one line of code" case, use `static inline` functions defined in the header. Also consider this: What does this print `int a_calls = 0;
int a(){ a_calls++; return a_calls; }

#define b(x) ((x) + (x)*(x))

int main(){ printf( "%d\n", b(a()) );
`?

Comment: @MohammadKholghi `What's the problem with macros?` - they have their place, but because they are literally (in C/C++) telling the preprocessor do a string replace before compilation, they aren't type safe and can lead to some very confusing errors when things change. `Which one do you prefer?` - I definitely prefer a whole function that does the same, particularly given that compilers would very likely inline that at any of the call sites ✌️

Comment: @datenwolf OK Sir, I always wanna learn more. If you have any good references for macros, or when to use/avoid them, share the link. Thank you.

Comment: @datenwolf it would be 7 btw. Thanks again, I've never thought about passing a function to a macro:)) I still don't get it. Why to use an inline function instead of a macro? Just because they have argument type in their prototype?

Comment: @msbit I use STM32, and the library has a looooot of macros. With what I've learned from you, I have no idea the professional programmers wrote it with multiple `#define`s. Any idea?

Comment: It's horses for courses; when you're developing for embedded systems you have to make different trade-offs. You are both constrained in terms of program size (increased if you inline functions) and in terms of stack size (increased if functions are not inlined).

Comment: @MohammadKholghi: **It was a trick question!** it may be 7, it maybe something else entirely. At a strict reading of the C standard you can't know, *because the order in which arguments to a statement are evaluated are implementation defined!* So depending on what compiler you're using, which optimization level and target architecture, you might get entirely different results.

Comment: @MohammadKholghi: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I decided to use #define for h & g, cause it's much easier and more standard.

#define might be easier but it's not really more standard. As a matter of fact, it's error-prone and hard to debug.
#define is usually used for faster processing as in contrary to function calls, it doesn't use RAM(stack) or processing time because it's simply replaced the compiler preprocessor.

With that established, it's fair to say #define is used when we want things to work faster.

For your purpose and because you want f() to stay private, there is another way by which you can accomplish that besides keeping things faster also, by using the `inline` keyword.

```
static inline void f(int x, int y, int z){
    //bla bla bla
}
```

the inline keyword instructs the compiler to optimize any call to f() usually by a code replacement as in #define.
Note that inline functions are not necessarily inlined by the compiler.
For more about that see http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/inline.html

Although you don't have to create h & g as functions. You can do something like that:

```
static inline void f(int x, int y, int z){
    //bla bla bla
}

void fInterface(int x, int y, int z){
    f(x, y, z);
}
```

then in the header file:

```
void fInterface(int x, int y, int z); // Prototype

#define h(x)       fInterface(x, 10, 10)
#define g(x, y)    fInterface(x, y, 10)
```

This code will have almost the same performance as exporting f() itself.

Hope you find that helpful!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the last suggestion - what's the difference between including a prototype for fInterface in the header, and including one for f itself? (Also, you've got some mismatched brackets in that code, which I presume are just mistakes.)

Comment: The suggestion is based on @Mohammad Kholghi restrictions in the question. For some reason he wants f() to be private. This might be because he using somebody else's code and don't want to change it. I will correct the missmatch bracket

Comment: I assumed the point of making f() private was so that it can only be called with certain pre-defined sets of values. Exposing a function with all the same parameters but a different name doesn't accomplish that.

Comment: If this is the case then functions g & h shall be defined like `void g(int x){f(x, 10, 10);}` and `void h(int x, int y){f(x, y, 10);}` while keeping f() as static inline to achieve performance.

Comment: Indeed, which is what other answers have suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use macros then.

Do it like this:

---

```
// header.h
void g(int x, int y, int z);
void h(int x, int y);
```

---

```
// implementation.c
#include "header.h"

static void f(int x, int y, int z){
    //bla bla bla
}

void g(int x, int y, int z){
    f(x, 10, 10); //10, 10 are hard coded
}

void h(int x, int y){
    f(x, y, 20); //20 is hard coded
}
```

---

Note the use of `static` on `f`. Without `f` being declared `static`, it will be visible to all the other translation units in your program regardless. If you really want to hide it, you must make it static.

Comment: What if I don't use static? Others can have a prototype of it?

Comment: Yes. There's no fundamental difference between declaring a function in a header, or declaring it inside the `.c` file. So if you have a function `f` that's not declared `static`, in any `.c` file you could declare and use it like `void f(int x,int y,int z); void k(){ f(1,2,3); }`

Answer (score 2):

#define creates a **macro**, which is **substituted by the compiler**. The code the macro creates doesn't even have to be a full C statement, it just acts as though the person using the macro had actually typed the expanded version.

It follows that a macro has to produce code that would be valid if the user of the macro was typing it in full. You can't "hide" anything in a macro, because it has to be expanded *before* the C code is compiled.

So if you want the function f() to be private, your original solution of using functions for g() and h() is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

You do NOT need to write the prototype of `f` in a header file.

In `secret_data.c`:

```
static void f(int x, int y, int z){   // F is defined here.
    //bla bla bla
}
// Because f is static, it is NOT visible outside this file.
    
void g(int x, int y, int z){
    f(x, 10, 10); // F is used here
}
void h(int x, int y){
    f(x, y, 20); // F is used here
}
```

Comment: If it's in the source file (`file.c`), so it's private. It's not in the header. What do you exactly mean by making it static??

Comment: @MohammadKholghi: headers are nothing special, at compilation an `#include` will literally do a "copy&paste" of the header contents at the place of the include. Instead of `#include`-ing a header, you could just declare the function prototype there, directly.